# get Video ID from PlaylistID Youtube?

Tags: java, android, json, youtube, playlist

how do I get a video id to a playlist

example 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXYiU_JCYtU&list=PL87FA01F68C540290

I want to get this kXYiU_JCYtU

have you any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You just do a String operation to cut the `&list` part off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<String> getVideoIds(ArrayList<String> urls){
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String url : urls) {
        ids.add(url.substring(url.indexOf('=')+1, url.indexOf('&')));
    }

    return ids;
}
```

Comment: thank you, can do this with an arraylist<string> and not a String?Thanks

Comment: ok thanks i solve, but if link is this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8_v7bZLo7g&index=2&list=PLobnYLRTMHk8M53dVftTdt3jDlQXoh8Fz

Comment: thanks anyway but I solve, can you take a look at my comment before this? thanks